# TShellExecuteInfo lpParameters and ">" symbol

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

This code calls Sqlite3.exe to do a database backup, but its not working because of the ">" symbol in the parameters. Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
procedure TfAdmin.DoDBBackup(ADBBackupFile: String);
var
  b, p, q: String;
  ps: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin

  b := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'PPDB.bak';
  p := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'sqlite3.exe';
  q := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'PPDB.db .dump > ' + b;  //here lies the problem

  ShowMessage(p + ' ' + q);
  fMain.UniConnection1.Close;
  try
    // Execute process and wait for it to terminate
    FillChar(ps, SizeOf(ps), 0);
    ps.cbSize := SizeOf(ps);
    ps.Wnd := Handle;
    ps.lpVerb := Nil;
    ps.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ps.lpFile := PChar(p);
    ps.lpParameters := PChar(q);
    ps.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

    if not ShellExecuteEx(@ps) then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    if ps.hProcess <> 0 then
    begin
      while WaitForSingleObject(ps.hProcess, 50) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
        application.ProcessMessages;
      CloseHandle(ps.hProcess);
    end;
  finally
    fMain.UniConnection1.Open;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Doesn't UniDAC contain a component for (SQLite) backup ? Or translated SQLite API headers ? This way may work but, uhm, is not much clean. What about [`TUniDump`](http://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/index.html?devart_unidac_tunidump.htm) for instance ? Wouldn't that work also with SQLite ?

Comment: Not as of yet. They say that they will implement the ONLINE BACKUP API in the next version (http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=25838&p=88118&hilit=sqlite+backup#p88118). I don't want to use TUniDump, as I needed something with good performance.

Comment: If you were having Delphi translation of the SQLite API, which I think you should already have as a part of UniDAC's SQLite implementation, you might be able (with a basic knowledge of C languages) build a code for [`SQLite Online Backup`](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` symbol instructs the command interpreter (cmd.exe) to redirect the output from the executable to a file. That works when the command interpretor is running the show. But here, there is no command interpretor.

There are a couple of options for you. A quite simple approach would be to ask the command interpretor to do the work. Use `cmd.exe` as your executable, pass the `/C` argument, and then the rest of the command line. If you want to be a good citizen, then use the value of the `COMSPEC` environment variable rather than hard coding `cmd.exe`.

A more grown up solution is to abandon the shell. Instead call `CreateProcess` directly. This is a little more involved. You have to create a file handle by calling `CreateFile`. Pass that handle to `CreateProcess` as the standard output file handle for the new process. You need to make sure that handles are inherited when you call `CreateProcess`.

One final point to make is that I really don't like your wait loop. You'd be far better off using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to block until queued messages arrive.

Comment: Does CreateProcess support execute and wait?

Comment: Of course. It returns handles for the newly created process and its main thread. You then wait until the process handle is signaled. And obviously close both handles when you are done with them. Step 1 is to get CreateProcess to do the work and not worry about stdout. Then tack on stdout handling. The MSDN docs for CreateProcess have all you need, so long as you are competent at reading such docs. Many Delphi programmers freak out at the sight of C code!!